# Accessing a website using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I'm trying to make an App for windows phone 7. This app will basiclly retrive information from a website that we use at work as our working schedule then rearrange the retrived info into a metro style UI. To be honest i don't know where to start ie. how to retrive the info. Should i use webclient class? httpwebrequest class? or something else?

All idea are appriciated

Here is a:- [image: pic. of the website i'm trying to access]

Update:-

Okay either im totally stupid or there is something wrong with the code i'm writing, that i can't figure it out. I was using the same code that you wrote BUT i still get an error that a definition for Proxy is not in the System.Net.WebRequest :( This is my code (the working version):-

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
        string url = "https://medinet.se/*****/schema/ibsef";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallBack), request);
    }

    private void ReadWebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest myRequest = (WebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            WebResponse myResponse = (WebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => parsertextBlock.Text = results);
            }
            myResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => parsertextBlock.Text = ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But if i add request.Proxy=null!! i get an error, that there is no definition for Proxy in (System.Net.WebRequest). And to be honest i start getting mad of this.

Yours

/Omar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is called ScreenScrape and i recommend you to use  Html Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ . Make a web service that retrieves the information from your website and rearranges to appropriate format. Use your web service by a phone and display your data.

Use WebRequest ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and WebResponse ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse(v=vs.100).aspx) .

TIP: Set the WebRequest.Proxy property ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy.aspx) to null, as i find it will be much faster.

**UPDATE:** More info on WebRequest Proxy property

Set `Proxy = null` on the WebRequest object to avoid an initial delay (that way the request won't start auto detecting proxies, which i find it's faster).

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("yourURL");
req.Proxy = null;
```

It's in the System.Net namespace so put an using statement `using System.Net;` or

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("yourURL");
req.Proxy = null;
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it really helping ;). The only thing that i can't do is the WebRequest.Proxy as i can't find it :( Do you have any idea if this property is available for silverlight and wp7?

Comment: Updated the question. Any idea why is that happening?